# How to see notifications when running full screen?

Tags: macos, notifications, fullscreen

I currently run XBMC/Kodi which runs in fullscreen so OS X notifications do not display on top. When the application is in windowed mode, notifications display as normal. I have looked through the settings and their seems to be no way to change this behavior.

Is anyone aware of a script/plugin/hack that will achieve my goal?

Comment: Does it use OS X's native fullscreen mode or its own? If it uses its own, it has to cover them because they are layered below the menu bar (which it has to cover).

Comment: Hi, I assume it user it's own as I can't see the menu bar or exit to window mode with the escape key.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still having this issue:

Press the <kbd>|</kbd> key (that's the pipe key, it typically shares a key with <kbd>\</kbd>) to exit Kodi's full-screen mode. Then, use macOS' full-screen button (the green one) to enter native full-screen. You should now see notifications in full-screen.